# A question on roots of a polynomial of degree $n$

Tags: polynomials

Under what conditions on cofficients of a polynomial $p(x)$, the roots of $p(x)$ are real and positive?

Comment: Discriminant is sufficient i suppose

Comment: One can also use general theory of equations such that we get only real roots

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: How do you define discriminant for a polynomial of $n$th degree?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem#Number_of_real_roots

Answer (score 1):

You also have the very nice *Sylvester-Hermite* theorem:

> Let $P(X)\in \mathbf R[X]$ a separable polynomial of degree $n$. Let $\zeta_1,\dots,\zeta_n$ be the (real or complex) roots of $P(X)$. Consider the Newton's sums $p_k=\zeta_1^k+\dots,\zeta_n^k,\quad k\ge 0$. To the real symmetric matrix
>   $$M=\begin{bmatrix}
> p_0&p_1&\dots& p_{n-1}\\
> p_1&p_2&\dots& p_n\\[-1ex]
> \vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\[-1ex]
> p_{n-1}& p_n&\dots& p_{2n-2}
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   is associated a quadratic form on $\mathbf R^n$.If $(s,t)$ is the signature of this quadratic form, the number of real roots of $P(X)$ is $\;s-t$.